# Weird problem of matlab when using coeffs and collect

Tags: matlab

Here is the code.

```
expr = 3/z + 2*z^2 + 7*z^3;
[cx,tx] = coeffs(expr)
```

This below is the error mesage.

> Error using symengine Polynomial expression expected.
>
> Error in sym/mupadmexnout (line 1177)
> out = mupadmex(fcn,args{:});
>
> Error in sym/coeffs (line 62)
> [cSym,tSym] = mupadmexnout('symobj::coeffsterms', p, args{:});

Another problem when using collect.

```
syms t z
sympref('PolynomialDisplayStyle','ascend');

a = 5;
n(t) = taylor(cos(t),t,'ExpansionPoint',pi,'Order',a);
s1(t) = taylor(1/(t^2),t,'ExpansionPoint',pi,'Order',a);
s2(t) = 1/(t-pi)^3;
nu(z) = subs(n, t-pi, z)
s(z) = expand(subs(s1 * s2, t-pi, z));
laurent(z) = expand(nu * s)
expr = 3/z + 2*z^2 + 7*z^3;
coeffs_z = collect(laurent,z)
```

$$\frac{-5,z^8 +{\left(4,\pi \right)},z^7 +{\left(60-3,\pi^2 \right)},z^6 +{\left(2,\pi^3 -48,\pi \right)},z^5 +{\left(36,\pi^2 -\pi^4 -120\right)},z^4 +{\left(96,\pi -24,\pi^3 \right)},z^3 +{\left(12,\pi^4 -72,\pi^2 \right)},z^2 +{\left(48,\pi^3 \right)},z-24,\pi^4 }{{\left(24,\pi^6 \right)},z^3 }$$

[image: output matlab]

It has the denominator 24*pi^6*z^3. How can I get rid of this denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message:

> Error using symengine Polynomial expression expected.

From the documentation:

> C = coeffs(p) returns coefficients of the polynomial p with respect to
> all variables determined in p by symvar.

The expression `expr = 3/z + 2*z^2 + 7*z^3;` is not a polynomial (`3/z` is not on the form `a*z^n` for `n>=0`).

The rest of the question is a separate question and should be in a different post.

Comment: Can you have a look at the 2nd question?